# KeyError 'image' formsets

Tags: django, image, keyerror, formset

It's my first time with formsets / images and this is my error:

```
 KeyError at /houses/new/

 'image'
```

This is my code:

models.py

```
class House(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='houses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    type = models.CharField(default='House', max_length=100)
    stories = models.IntegerField()
    square_feet = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()


# Class is for the houses images
class Image(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, default=None, related_name="images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='image')
```

forms.py

```
# This is the blueprint for House forms
class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField(label="Address:")
    type = forms.CharField(label="Type of House (House, Condo, Cottage):")
    stories = forms.IntegerField(label="House Stories:")
    square_feet = forms.IntegerField(label='Square Feet:')
    class Meta:
        model = House
        fields = ['address', 'type', 'stories', 'square_feet', 'description']


# This is the form for images
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image',)
```

views.py

```
def post_house(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Image, form=ImageForm, extra=10)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        house_form = AlbumForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=Image.objects.none())

        if house_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post_form = house_form.save(commit=False)
            post_form.user = request.user
            post_form.save()

            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                image = form['image']
                photo = Image(house=post_form, image=image)
                photo.save()

            messages.success(request, "New house listing success")
            house = post_form
            return redirect('houses:details', house_id=house.pk)
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        house_form = AlbumForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Image.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'houses/house_form.html', {'house_form': house_form, 'formset': formset})
```

house_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container">
    <h4>Post a New Home</h4>
    <form id="post_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{house_form}}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {{ form }} <br>
        {% endfor %}


        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

It must be some relation between my form key and what each form in formset is taking. That being said they're both 'image' so I don't see the problem. Please let me know if you got an idea. Thanks a ton!

Comment: please try to print `form` after formset validation to see the content of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
if formset.is_valid():
   for form in formset:
       data = form.cleaned_data
       image = data.get('image')
       photo = Image(house=post_form, image=image)
       photo.save()
```